# How to implement Try and Except into my code so it automatically restarts when connection to database fails?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, try-except

I have a python script that pulls sql queries from a database but unfortunately the database has performance issue and sometime kills my script. Since my script is using a list of 20,000 arguments from a text file it will take my script a while to run and it will fail many times. As a result I would like to implement try and except into my script so it will automatically continue retrying even when the connection to the database is lost momentarily. The error message I get is cannot connect to database which I know isn't true since my script works without the try and except statements. My code is below and I would greatly appreciate your assistance!

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)

import re
import sys
import json
import pprint

outfilepath = "crtsh_output/crtsh_flat_file"

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'

def connect_to_db():
    filepath = 'forager.txt'
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        try:
            for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                print(domain_name)
                domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

                conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_k$
FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''',(domain_name,))


                unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()

                pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

                outfilepath = "crtsh1" + ".json"
                with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))

        except:
            print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

**Updated Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)

import re
import sys
import json
import pprint

outfilepath = "crtsh_output/crtsh_flat_file"

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
cursor = conn.cursor()

def connect_to_db():
    filepath = 'forager.txt'

    with open(filepath) as fp:
            for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                while True:
                    try:
                        print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                        print(domain_name)
                        domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

                        cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_keyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_keySize(c.certificate), x509_publicKeyMD5(c.certificate), x509_publicKey(c.certificate), x509_rsaModulus(c.certificate), x509_serialNumber(c.certificate), x509_signatureHashAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_signatureKeyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_subjectName(c.certificate), x509_name(c.certificate), x509_name_print(c.certificate), x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_subjectKeyIdentifier(c.certificate), x509_extKeyUsages(c.certificate), x509_certPolicies(c.certificate), x509_canIssueCerts(c.certificate), x509_getPathLenConstraint(c.certificate), x509_altNames(c.certificate), x509_altNames_raw(c.certificate), x509_cRLDistributionPoints(c.certificate), x509_authorityInfoAccess(c.certificate), x509_print(c.certificate), x509_anyNamesWithNULs(c.certificate), x509_extensions(c.certificate), x509_tbscert_strip_ct_ext(c.certificate), x509_hasROCAFingerprint(c.certificate)
                                        FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci
                                        WHERE c.id = ci.certificate_id
                                        AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName'
                                        AND lower(ci.name_value) = lower('domain_name')
                                        AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp();''')
                        unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()
                    except:
                        print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")
                        continue
                    break




                pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

                outfilepath = "crtsh1" + ".json"
                with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

Comment: 20,000 arguments to a function? Have I misread or are you sure to mean that?

Comment: @roganjosh I have 20,000 values that I would like to throw into the domain argument. Do you have any suggestions of how to help?

Comment: I'm a bit lost on your question. Submit one query using `IN (some_list_here)`?

Comment: Actually, I think `IN` might be limited to 1000 values.

Comment: @roganjosh So I have a .txt file with 20,000 domains and I'm looping through each domain and use the domain_name as an parameter in my sql query. If look at my sql query you will see a parameter called domain_name

Comment: oh, I'm familiar with the query because I think we debated over it yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled using a `while` loop. It will break if there is no exception. This could, in theory, continue forever so it may be wise to add an incrementing variable and a stopping conditional. You could also check the exception is the one for your issue and not some other issue.

```
for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
    while True:
        try:
            # connect to db
        except:
            print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")
            continue
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I now get an error saying that Unable to connect to database for each line. Do you have any idea of how to fix this? I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: you should open the database once. Outside the loop. In your try loop, execute the query once you leave the for loop you can close the connection

Comment: thanks @chaggy Do I want cursor.execute and cursor.fetchall() inside the loop or just one of those?

Comment: that's correct. just the minimum amount of code necessary

Answer (score 0):

`connect_to_db()` is a misnomer, it's doing far more than that. Take your:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

lines out of the loop. There is no need to keep reconnecting. Establish one connection and loop through the values you want to execute. Pass the list of what you want to execute as an argument to the function.

```
def connect_to_db():
    filepath = 'forager.txt'
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        try:
            for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                print(domain_name)
                domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()


                cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_k$
FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''',(domain_name,))


                unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()

                pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

                outfilepath = "crtsh1" + ".json"
                with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))

        except:
            print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")
```

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh What about cursor.execute? Should I put it before the While True statement inside my loop or completely outside the loop. Also, where should I put cursor.fetchall()?

Comment: @bedford Hoist `conn = ...` and `cursor = conn.cursor()` out of the loop, before `with open(filepath) as fp:`. The rest stays the same, I think.

Comment: @bedford In other words, you establish the connection once and commit multiple values. You don't need a fresh connection and cursor for every value you commit.

Comment: Now the script just prints out the domain_names really quickly and gives a unable to connect to database error. I've updated my code above to show you what changes I made. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @bedford try my updated code. You're leaning on global values here so it's bug-prone from the start.

Comment: Thanks again for your response! Still getting that unable to connect message. Here is the traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2:38pm", line 63, in <module>
    connect_to_db()
  File "2:38pm", line 55, in connect_to_db
    pprint.pprint(unique_domains)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'unique_domains' referenced before assignment

Comment: @bedford you're not getting that from the code you posted. For sure it's later in your code that isn't posted, where `try` has failed.

Comment: Do you have any idea of at what line try has failed?

Comment: I posted all of my code so it's not anything I'm adding in